# autofilter method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, autofilter

ActiveSheet.Range("a1:b1").AutoFilter

the above code works fine but sometimes gives error 'autofilter method of range class failed'.
my intention is to enable filtering for some columns without any criteria. is there any better way?

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes??? And what specific is in your book you try to apply filter on?

Answer (score 6):

As a rule I always turn off all prior filters, just in case.

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False      'turn off prior filters
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B1").AutoFilter   'turn on new clean filter
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just dealing with a similar situation, where Range would not execute AutoFilter() no matter what I did.  I was able to solve it by removing Range from the equation entirely, using Selection as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a1:b1").Select()
Application.Selection.AutoFilter()
```

Whatever the problem was, selection bypassed it entirely.