# Excel VBA Programming : Code Needed to Be Modified

Tags: vba, excel

I have displayed YES if the Data of Column C>=0.05 and NO if it is not satisfied . Also , I have done same with Column D in the Excel. The program Code is Given.

Now , I want to Modify my program . I want to display all the Output in single display Box like in Qbasic Programming , C programming  . Also, If My output is YES , Just I need to display YES and If it is NO , I need to Display corresponding values of A cell .

The Code is Given

```
Sub ArrayLoops1() 
 Dim arrCMarks() 
 Dim arrDMarks() 
 Dim i, j As Integer
 a = 0
 b = 0 
 'For Column C

arrCMarks = Range("C2:C1439").Value
For i = LBound(arrCMarks, 1) To UBound(arrCMarks, 1)
If arrCMarks(i, 1) >= 0.005 Then
a = a + 1
End If
 Next i
If a = 0 Then
MsgBox (" YES ")
Else
MsgBox ("NO")
End If    

' For Column D

arrDMarks = Range("D2:D1439").Value
 For j = LBound(arrDMarks, 1) To UBound(arrDMarks, 1)
If arrDMarks(j, 1) >= 0.005 Then
b = b + 1
End If
 Next j
If b = 0 Then
MsgBox ("YES")
Else
MsgBox ("NO")
End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Please give two examples (one for yes, one for no). In each example, show a small grid of numbers together with the desired output.

Comment: If C or D column has data 0.006 on fifthcell . Then I should Print NO with its corresponding value in fifth Cell  of Column A . If data Contains 0.004 Then Print only YES . Do Same for Column D But I need to print Output in Single display Box for all data i.e Display box will give all the output in single window like C , QBASIC @Ruud

Comment: If C or D column has data 0.006 on fifthcell . Then I should Print NO with its corresponding value of Column A (fifth Cell of Column A ). If data Contains 0.004 Then Print only YES . Do Same for Column D But I need to print Output in Single display Box for all data i.e Display box will give all the output in single window like C , QBASIC   @LukePark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this will output a one msgbox:

```
Sub ArrayLoops1()
    Dim arrCMarks()
    Dim arrDMarks()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim otptStr As String

    'For Column C

    arrCMarks = Range("C2:C1439").Value
    For i = LBound(arrCMarks, 1) To UBound(arrCMarks, 1)
        If arrCMarks(i, 1) >= 0.005 Then
            otptStr = otptStr & "C: " & arrCMarks(i, 1) & " A" & i + 1 & ": " & Range("A" & i + 1).text & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next i


    ' For Column D

    arrDMarks = Range("D2:D1439").Value
    For j = LBound(arrDMarks, 1) To UBound(arrDMarks, 1)
        If arrDMarks(j, 1) >= 0.005 Then
            otptStr = otptStr & "D: " & arrDMarks(j, 1) & " A" & j + 1 & ": " & Range("A" & j + 1).text & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next j

    MsgBox otptStr, vbOKOnly, "Both Columns"

End Sub
```

It will output any that are greater than the .005.

Comment: Yeah , Thank you But I need Single Msgbox for two Columns not Double .

Comment: While Running above program , Run time Error 9 ( Subscript out of Range message is displayed) indicating error in  otptStr = otptStr & "D: " & arrDMarks(i, 1) & " A" & i + 1 & ": " & Range("A" & i + 1).Value & vbCrLf  . I am unable to figure out what is wrong !!

Comment: @adityalamichhane see edit.

Comment: Yeah It is Good Now . But There has been problem to display the data of A column . It is in the format of  9:22:25 AM,9:22:35 AM,...... in my original data .  Please, Help me to display this.

Comment: @adityalamichhane see edit

Comment: Thank you .The Code is Perfect . Finally, I just wanted to have some space in Display Box Between Column C and D . Its looking so Compact . And also , some space in between data of Column C or Column D and Its corresponding data of A column in the Display Box .

Comment: At this point, try to modify on your own.  `vbCrLf` is the command to add lines.  and put spaces in the code where you want them.

Comment: While Operating Code for 6 Columns . There was 17 violating Conditions in the Display box . It was good till the 16th row of the display box but in 17th Row of Display Box,It was showing only the value of Column which is violating the condition but not showing corresponding value of A column ( like 9:22:25 Am).Except this I didnt find any problem.

Comment: @adityalamichhane that is because msgbox has a 255 character limit.  When it reaches the limit it stops showing text.

Comment: Cant we make the size of Msgbox high ? or Is there any alternatives to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Nope it is a limitations of excel.  You would need to split it up by column into separate msgboxes.

Comment: Please Help me to slightly modify the code ,If Data of Column C is greater than 0.005. Then Shift to Corresponding cell of Column D. Example: if the data of 5th row in Column C is greater than 0.005. Then move to 5th row of D column (Ignore the first four rows) and test the similar condition (Data being greater than 0.009, display YES otherwise Display NO only) for next 5 rows of Column D (from 5th row of column D to 10th row of Column D). if the condition becomes NO, Then move back to 6th row of Column C .

Comment: @adityalamichhane this is a new question, please post a new question.

Comment: Okay , You can view here ,Hope you will Help again : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677121/excel-vba-programming-slight-modification-needed

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understood your problem correctly:

If at least one of the values in Column C is bigger than or equal 0.005, you want to display a MsgBox saying "Yes", if no value is bigger or equal one that says "No" and the same thing again for column D?

And now you want to combine that in a single MsgBox?

In that case, do the following:

1. Format your code to have a better overview
2. We can not stop iterating anymore because we need to find all values.
3. Construct a String out of multiple elements

Resulting Code:

```
Sub ArrayLoops1()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim a As Boolean, b As Boolean
    Dim MsgString As String

    MsgString = "Column C: "

    'For Column C

    For i = 2 To 1439
        If Range("C" & i).Value >= 0.005 Then
            If a = False Then
                a = True
                MsgString = MsgString & "NO, values from coumn A are:" & vbCrLf
            End If

            'Add value from column A
            MsgString = MsgString & Range("A" & i).Value & vbCrLf

            'Can not stop iterating since we need to find all values
        End If
    Next i

    If a = False Then
        MsgString = MsgString & "YES" & vbCrLf
    End If

    MsgString = MsgString & "Column D: "


    ' For Column D

    For j = 2 To 3
        If Range("D" & i).Value >= 0.005 Then
            If b = False Then
                b = True
                MsgString = MsgString & "NO, values from coumn A are:" & vbCrLf
            End If

            'Add value from column A
            MsgString = MsgString & Range("A" & i).Value & vbCrLf

            'Can not stop iterating since we need to find all values
        End If
    Next j

    If b = False Then
        MsgString = MsgString & "YES"
    End If

    'Display the message
    MsgBox MsgString
End Sub
```

BTW, the line

```
Dim i, j As Integer
```

results in i beeing a Variant (not good) and only j beeing an Integer.
Better:

```
Dim i as Integer, j as Integer
```

Bye, vat

**Edit:** If result is No, the corresponding value from column A is displayed (see comments below)

**Edit 2:** The code now does not stop iterating since we need to find all violating values. All corresponding values from column A are now shown.

Comment: Thank you Understood My problem almost correctly but If I should Print NO . I should also display at what Corresponding value of Column A the system is saying NO . Is it clear ?

Comment: I guess you want only that one value that violates the condition to be displayed?

Comment: No I want all the Corresponding Values of Column A that violates the condition in Column C and D  .

Comment: I edited my answer to match your needs.

Comment: The edit will only give the first that violates, and he wants all of them.  You need to move it into the loop and forget the boolean.

Comment: Also be careful, the array is starts at the second row, but the lbound will be 1 so the corresponding Cell in column A will be row i+1.

Comment: Keep in mind that we evaluate 1438 rows. Showing every single violating value would make the MsgBox very big

Comment: Folks, I'm going to bed now, we'll continue tomorrow

Comment: Hense the number of down votes and why many of us have not attempted to give answers, because it will lead to more questions.

Comment: In my data , There is only 3 or 4 violating Conditions out of 1438 rows . So I think having these will not make Msg box too large. @vatbub

Comment: In the edited code above . It doesnt show the corresponding value of A . It only shows the Heading of Column A. @vatbub

Comment: Er, nope, it shows the value

Comment: So now, all values from column A are shown. The reason why you thought only the column header was shown was the bug @ScottCraner mentioned. It's now fixed too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you (or your users) are totally obsessed with popup dialogs, I would suggest to use a **filter** instead.
Such a filter would hide the majority of rows, leaving only the ones where column C or D, or both, satisfy some condition. The reason for a row to remain visible, will be reported in a separate column.

```
Sub FilterCD()
    ' Use column Z to report violating columns.
    ' In this example:  C  = the value in column C > 0.005
    '                   D  = the value in column D < 0.006
    '                   CD = both
    Range("Z2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(IF(C2>0.005,""C"",""""), IF(D2<0.006,""D"",""""))"
    Range("Z2:Z6").FillDown

    ' Hide rows where column Z is empty.
    AutoFilterMode = False
    Cells.AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
```

Notes:

- Adding more column in addition to C and D, is straightforward; `CONCATENATE` accepts any number of arguments.
- You need a header row above your data to make this work. In other words, your data should start from row 2. Considering your original code, I guess that is already the case with you.
- You can use Ctrl+Shift+L to undo the filter afterwards.
- On big Excels sheets, I expect this code to be a lot faster than anything using `For` loops. But I must admit I did not profile it.

Please let me know if there is anything in my answer that does not meet your demands.

Comment: Yeah that would be also good solution . But the above code displayed Run Time Error '1004' (Autofilter Method of Range class failed') . I am unable to figure whats wrong . Please Help me

Comment: Based on advice from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827833/autofilter-method-of-range-class-failed) and many other sources, I have edited my answer, adding a line `AutoFilterMode = False`; hope that helps.

Comment: I am finding this method best for my Problem But I am not getting Whats going on in the code! . Actually I need to Operate on 6 Columns where there is different condition like Greater than 0.005 , less than 0.006 . Condition is Different for Different Columns. If Condition is Violated in Column C , It should  show that column C violated Condition and its corresponding value in A column and like this for other Columns . Please Help me

Comment: See my edit; please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I need to filter on a condition on different columns . But this filters in one column and show its correspondng values of another column . I found the correct answer . I think you shouldn't worry about it now .