# How to fix an "AutoFilter method of Range class failed" error?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to run a code in order to gather data from a general data tab and spit it out/format it properly in another tab.

This is for an VBA application code. I have tried running it multiple times and it is giving me the same error "AutoFilter method of Range class failed".. The current range I have is for all of the sheet that contains data in it... I am wondering if it is possible to fix the error and also make the range so that it will select everything in the table columns A:BN. My thought process for this is that if I eliminate the cell location/range and only include the column range, I will be able to execute this on different files of different sizes.

```
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BN$17607").AutoFilter Field:=2, 
      Criteria1:="11"
  ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=2
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BN$17607").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:= _
     "Additonal Spend"
  ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-2
  Columns("A:A").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
  ActiveSheet.Name = "RegionalSubmit"
```

The actual error is a

> '1005': "AutoFilter method of Range class failed"

Also note that the code itself runs perfectly fine by itself but when I created a MasterMacro to list each macro to run under, this is when I get that error code!

Comment: Did you try turning the autofilter *off* before applying it again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827833/autofilter-method-of-range-class-failed?rq=1

Comment: At the end of my code the filter is reset back to nothing, so I don't think that should be an issue....

Comment: Is the `ActiveSheet` potentially not the sheet you want the filter on?

Comment: The ActiveSheet is the sheet I want the filter on because its the sheet I am pulling data from.

Comment: I get a 1004 error with that same message *if* column A doesn't have a header/text.

Comment: Column A does have a header, every column has a header/text. Nonetheless that's irrelevant to the error due to the range of the filter.